# How do I count and return only the objects in my ArrayList that are true?

Tags: java, arrays, oop, object, arraylist

I want to count all the objects that are true and return it (as I have tried to do in countNational. The method I use to assign an object as true/false is in a different class and named NationalMessage. I have pasted it below the main method.

```
public class Ex6 
{
 public static int countNational (ArrayList<Message> messageList) 
 {

 int countTrue = 0; //will count those that are true

 for (int i = 0; i<= messageList.size(); i++)
 {
     if(messageList.get(i)==true) //GETTING ERROR SAYING CAN'T COMPARE BOOLEAN
     countTrue = countTrue + 1;
 }
 return countTrue;
 }
 public static void main(String[] args)
 { 
 ArrayList<Message> messageList = new ArrayList<Message>();
 messageList.add(new NationalMessage("UKJohn","UKMark","aa"));
 messageList.add(new NationalMessage("UKJohn","FRJean","aa"));
 messageList.add(new Message("Mike","John","aa"));
 System.out.println(countNational(messageList));
 }
}
```

************************* THE BELOW IS A METHOD FROM A SEPERATE CLASS CALLED NATIONAL MESSAGE*****************************

```
public NationalMessage(String ssender, String rreceiver, String ccontent)
{
    super(ssender,rreceiver,ccontent);

    if (ssender.equals("UK") && rreceiver.equals("UK"))
    {
        isNational = true;
    }

    else 
    {
        isNational = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to check for `isNational`? How about changing it to `if(messageList.get(i).isNational)` ?

Comment: How should we know that `Message` is true or not?

Comment: There are several issues with your code. The `ssender` and `rreceiver` (whatever the point of the repetition of the first letter is…) are not supposed to equal `"UK"`, but to start with it.

Comment: I believe the question should say `How to return the count of true objects in an ArrayList`

Comment: @dejvuth The method NationalMessage is in a separate class, so when do try the method you suggested, I keep getting an error saying cannot find variable isNational. How would I fix this?

Comment: @Pshemo via the method (which is in a separate class) called NationalMessage

Comment: @navysoul `NationalMessage` doesn't have return type which suggests it is a constructor, not a method. Purpose of constructors is to properly initialize object, not to return anything. If you want to use some property of initialized object (like value of field) you need to either make that field public (not advised since it defeats encapsulation), or (preferred) by getter which will return value held by that field. In this case you want to return value of `isNational` field. Assuming it is private one, create getter like `boolean isNational(){return isNational;}` and use it after `get(i)`.

Comment: @Pshemo I did that - created a getter method etc. But, it's saying it cannot find the method (getIsNational). Is this because it is in a separate class? How would I access it is it's in a separate class that's not a superclass?

Answer (score 4):

using a stream in java8 is jsut as simple as filtering the list

```
long xx = myList.stream().filter(t -> t.isNational).collect(Collectors.counting());
```

or to get the list

```
List<NationalMessage> x = myList.stream().filter(t->t.isNational).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Don't you mean `long count = ...count();`?

Comment: and for counting: `myList.stream().filter(t->t.isNational).count()` or `myList.stream().filter(t->t.isNational).collect(Collectors.counting())`

Comment: @StefanWarminski as the title ask to return the items too, it is correct as it is now. It is easier to get count from the list that the list from the count ;)

Comment: @AxelH method's name is `countNational` ;) does not sound like `getNationals`. But you're right, the idea should be clear.

Answer (score 2):

Change:

```
if(messageList.get(i)==true)
```

to:

```
if(messageList.get(i).isNational==true)
```

**Why?**

Because you can compare apples with apples and oranges with oranges.
On right hand side of  == , **true** is present. So on left hand side also there should be a boolean or an expression that results in a  boolean.
Your original expression messageList.get(i) does not result in a boolean. Rather it results in an object or null.
In some languages like C, a null may be interpreted as false and non-null may be interpreted as true but in Java, it's not so. 
You have to be explicit about the booleans.
For e.g. left hand side expression in your case could be :
messageList.get(i)!=null which would evaluate to true/false

Comment: "_Because..._" ;) if OP don't notice that, an explanation is probably needed.

Comment: I'm getting an error saying "cannot find variable isNational". isNational is in a different class. How would I access isNational then?

Comment: Do both your classes - Message and NationaMessage contain isNational or does NationaMessage extends Message? because as per your code your are adding both of them to the list.

Comment: @Akshay I have three classes. Superclass named Message (Which is not the one I shared above - the one I shared above is called Ex6), a subclass of Message called NationalMessage, and Ex6. I need to access isNational which is in the subclass NationalMessage. How would I get access to a variable in a subclass?